# Chart filter not working as expected

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have a dataset like this:

```
Item   Value   Date          Show  
IT1    10      2012 01 01    1  
IT1    9       2012 01 02    1  
IT1    11      2012 01 03    1  
IT2    8       2012 01 01    1  
IT2    5       2012 01 02    1  
IT2    3       2012 01 03    1
```

In a chart I have a filter which checks the `Show` value and leaves only rows where `Show` is 1. The problem is that instead of 2 items I see only 1, even though both of them have `show = 1`.

**EDIT:**

Filter expressions i tried:
`=Fields!Show.Value` = `=1`
`=CInt(Fields!Show.Value)` = `=1`
`=CInt(Fields!Show.Value)` = `=CInt(1)`
`=CBool(Fields!Show.Value)` = `=CBool(1)`
`=CBool(Fields!Show.Value)` = `=CBool(True)`

After using these expressions i get dataset like this:

```
Item   Value   Date          Show  
IT1    10      2012 01 01    1
```

Comment: For your dataset all the values are having Show=1

Comment: Not allways. But now i have problems with dataset where all values have show=1. Why does it filter those items?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. What is the filter expression you're using? What specific data rows are unexpectedly being filtered by that expression? You're not providing enough details for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your example - your dataset has 6 rows where show = 1 ?

Anyway, SSRS Filters are so obscure and generally best avoided, but this technique seems to be more reliable:

Filter Expression: =Fields!Show.Value = 1
Result Type: Boolean
Operator: =
Value: True